# what does "with query time()" means in prometheus rule

Tags: prometheus, rules

In the following sample rule, What's the meaning for
{{ with query "time()" }}{{ . | first | value | humanizeTimestamp }}{{ end }}? I search the prometheus doc, but can't find the definition.

```
   - alert: SCPIngressTrafficRateAboveMajorThreshold
    annotations:
      timestamp: ' {{ with query "time()" }}{{ . | first | value | humanizeTimestamp }}{{ end }} '
      description: 'Ingress Traffic Rate at locality: {{$labels.ocscp_locality}} is above major threshold (i.e. 1400 mps)'
      summary: 'namespace: {{$labels.kubernetes_namespace}}, podname: {{$labels.kubernetes_pod_name}}, timestamp: {{ with query "time()" }}{{ . | first | value | humanizeTimestamp }}{{ end }}: Current Ingress Traffic Rate is {{ $value | printf "%.2f" }} mps which is above 80 Percent of Max MPS(1700)'
     # Provide app and kubernetes_namespace of scp deployed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it will show the timestamp in a more readable format.

You can see more details about the Prometheus functions in the [TEMPLATE REFERENCE](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_reference/) section in the Prometheus documentation.

There're good examples in the [TEMPLATE EXAMPLES](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_examples/) section in the Prometheus documentation.